# Constructing a complementary subspace given the quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In the textbook I am reading (*A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics* by Szekeres), the definition of the quotient space of a vector space $V$ given a subspace $W$, $V/W$, is motivated by the desire to find a way to construct complementary subspaces to that fixed subspace $W$ (ie. it is defined after giving the typical nonconstructive proof of the existence of complementary subspaces using Zorn's Lemma).

The result about all complementary subspaces to $W$ being isomorphic to $V/W$ and thus to each other is proved, and then it is stated that "the quotient space is a method for constructing the 'canonical complement' to the subspace".

Now it's quite clear to me how one can construct the quotient space from a complementary subspace using the explicit isomorphism (called the quotient map by Axler, $T: U \to V/W$ defined by $T(u) = u +W$), but the converse is not clear. Obviously things are not that simple since a given coset is just a set and is not given to us in the form $u+W$ for $u \in U$, with $U$ the complementary subspace which we want to construct! There is no clear $T^{-1}$ to use.

Therefore, my question is, given a quotient space, how does one in general construct a complementary subspace? Answers which give an example of such a construction and/or mention applications in which such a construction is useful would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no canonical complement to a subspace $W\subset V$. The quotient is a canonical thing, but the quotient doesn’t naturally sit inside the space you started with, choosing a way for it to do this is exactly choosing a complement.

I think a good way to appreciate this issue is to take a line through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then any other line will be a complement, so we have lots of choice for this other line. Taking the quotient shows these lines are all isomorphic as vector spaces, but they sit inside $\mathbb{R}^2$ in different ways.

However, sometimes we do have a canonical way to get a complement, namely, if there is a nondegenerate definite inner product floating around on your vector space. Then the orthogonal complement with respect to this form is a distinguished complement. This is often the case in physics, where you are in a Hilbert space, so that might be why the author views complements as canonical.

Having a definite inner product on your vector space is something that doesn’t occur over an arbitrary field however, there are fields where no such thing is possible. Away from $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ one should really think of complements being totally noncanonical, with no extra structure on your vector space which makes such a special choice.

Finally I want to remark that this issue is a very real one which relates to very interesting geometry. One can consider all the $k$ dimensional sub spaces of a vector space at once, and this is a compact smooth manifold (or a smooth projective variety). Then by choosing a fixed subspace, or family of sub spaces, one can understand the space of all $k$ dimensional subspaces by their intersections with these fixed reference subspaces. This leads to beautiful results on these spaces (called Grassmannians), all based on the highly complicated structure of how vector spaces can intersect!

Comment: Thank you for this lovely answer!

Comment: Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

**Question:** "Therefore, my question is, given a quotient space, how does one in general construct a complementary subspace?"

**Answer:** If $k$ is a field and $V$ is a $k$-vector space, it follows (if you accept the "axiom of choice") that $V$ has a basis $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$. From this property it follows that $V$ is a projective $k$-module: For any surjective map

$$\rho: U \rightarrow W \rightarrow 0$$

of $k$-vector spaces and any map of $k$-vector spaces $\psi: V \rightarrow W$ there is a (non-unique) map of $k$-vector spaces $\phi: V \rightarrow U$ with

$$\rho \circ \phi = \psi.$$

If you have an exact sequence of $k$-vector spaces

$$0 \rightarrow W \rightarrow U \rightarrow^p U/W \rightarrow 0$$

it follows there is a section $s$ of $p$: There is a map of $k$-vector spaces $s: U/W \rightarrow U$ with $p \circ s = Id$ is the identity map. When you choose a section $s$
you choose a complement to $W$ in $U$ in the following sense: Let $u:=s \circ p$.
It follows

$$u^2:= u \circ u = s \circ p \circ s \circ p = s \circ p =u$$

hence $u: U \rightarrow U$ is an idempotent endomorphism. From this it follows you may write

$$U \cong W \oplus Im(u).$$

Hence choosing a section $s$ you get a complement $Im(u)$ to the subspace $W \subseteq U$.

Given any section $s$ of $p$ and any $k$-linear map $v:U/W \rightarrow W$, it follows the
new map

$$s+v: U/W \rightarrow U$$

is another section of $p$. The set of sections of $p$ is "parametrized" by the vector space

$$Hom_k(U/W,W).$$

Hence the "set of complements of $W$ in $U$" is a large set in general: There is no unique complement.

**Question:** "Answers which give an example of such a construction and/or mention applications in which such a construction is useful would be very much appreciated!"

**Example:** If $G:=SL(V)$ where $V:=\mathbb{C}\{e_1,e_2\}$ and if $U$ is any finite dimensional $G$-module that is not irreducible you may always find a non-zero irreducible sub-$G$-moule $W \subseteq U$. You get an exact sequence of modules

$$S1.\text{  }0 \rightarrow W \rightarrow U \rightarrow U/W \rightarrow 0.$$

The sequence $S1$ always (by the above argument) splits as a sequence of vector spaces.
Hence you may always write $U \cong W \oplus Im(u)$ for some idempotent endomorphism $u$. In this case - since $G$ is a semi simple algebraic group you may choose the complement to be a $G$-submodule: You may choose a complement

$$D1.\text{   }U \cong W \oplus W'$$

where $W' \subseteq U$ is a sub-$G$-module. Groups such as $SL(V)$ arise in mathematics and mathematical physics. In many applications you need to calculate such a decomposition as in $D1$. By induction you get a decomposition

$$ U \cong W_1\oplus \cdots \oplus W_k$$

where $W_i$ is an irreducible $G$-module.

In general given any partition

$$\lambda_n \leq \lambda_{n-1} \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_1$$

you get an irreducible $SL(\mathbb{C}^n)$-module denoted $\mathbb{S}_{\lambda}(\mathbb{C}^n)$. Given another partition $\mu$ you get the module

$$W:=\mathbb{S}_{\mu}(\mathbb{S}_{\lambda}(\mathbb{C}^n)),$$

and the module $W$ is not irreducible in general.  It is an open problem to decompose $W$ into its irreducible components.

**Example:** Let $V:=\mathbb{C}^n$ and consider the canonical map

$$ m:V \otimes_k \wedge^k V \rightarrow \wedge^{k+1} V$$

It follows $ker(m) \subsetneq V\otimes_k \wedge^k V$ is an irreducible strict sub-module, hence $V\otimes_k \wedge^k V$ is not irreducible.